# List returned from function not containing correct results

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have the following function which extracts non-sequential files names associated with the index items:

```
check_increment(plot_inf):

    lists = sorted(plot_inf.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples
    x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

    bad_steps =[]

    for item in range(len(x)-1):

        diff = (y[item+1])-(y[item])

        if diff <> increment_value:
            bad_steps.append((x[item]))
    return bad_steps
```

Here is how I call it

```
results = check_increment(plot_info)

print results
```

This is the result:

```
['image_D2017-06-26T17-02-01-994022Z_2.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-02-
327353Z_0.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-02-660684Z_1.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-
26T17-02-02-994007Z_2.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-03-327330Z_0.jpg', 
'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-03-660654Z_1.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-03-
993973Z_2.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-04-327305Z_0.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-
26T17-02-04-660625Z_1.jpg']
```

When I run the code stand alone it works:

```
plot_dict = {'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-03-327330Z_0.jpg': 6231, 'image_D2017-
06-26T17-02-02-660684Z_1.jpg': 6229, 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-02-
327353Z_0.jpg': 622, 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-04-660625Z_1.jpg': 6235, 
'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-03-993973Z_2.jpg': 6233, 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-
02-994007Z_2.jpg': 6230, 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-01-994022Z_2.jpg': 6227, 
'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-04-993951Z_2.jpg': 6236, 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-
03-660654Z_1.jpg': 6232, 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-04-327305Z_0.jpg': 6234}

 increment_value = 1

 lists = sorted(plot_dict.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples
 x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

bad_steps =[]

for item in range(len(x)-1):

  diff = (y[item+1])-(y[item])

  if diff <> increment_value:
      bad_steps.append((x[item]))

  print bad_steps
```

with this result:

```
['image_D2017-06-26T17-02-01-994022Z_2.jpg', 'image_D2017-06-26T17-02-02-327353Z_0.jpg']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting your `increment_value` from in the main script? Also, can you post a test case when the function doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Made some updates.  The increment_value is passed into the script as an argument.  I tried passing it in as part of the function call but I get the same results.  I also queried the bad_steps variable within the function and it does contain the 2 expected results.  It seems that the returned list is 'different'.

Comment: Can not reproduce. Works fine both inline and as a function.

Comment: you do not have an indent before diff = (y[item+1])-(y[item]) in second example. Mb this is an error. But i think the problem is in incremet_value as zwer said before

Comment: @VasilyBronsky - sorry, bad formatting when copying the code above.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the source of the problem and @zwer was in the right place.  When called from by full script the Increment_value argument was coming in as a string. So to fix the problem I modified the following line to convert it to an int

```
increment_value = int(args.increment)
```

It worked in the standalone because it was declared as an int from the start.

Thanks for all you help on this!